# ImportError About libcublas.so.9.0

Tags: python, cuda

I'm facing a strange problem about 'ImportError'.

I have installed cuda9.0 and cuDNN7.0 for running tensorflow-gpu 1.5.0. After that, when I run

```
python3
```

in terminal, and run

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I can import it successfully. However, when I run

```
sudo python3
```

and type

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

again, I got an error like this:

> ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Besides, when I use

```
sudo spyder3
```

or

```
sudo pycharm
```

or

```
sudo jupyter
```

and import tensorflow in it, I will get the same error.

So, I wonder why the command 'sudo' can result in such error? And how can I fix it? Is there anyone can help me?

Thank you!!!!!

This is my first time to ask in 'askubuntu', and maybe I wrote in a wrong format. If so, I apologize for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I find a resolution to this problem: just run IDE without sudo.

Then, if there is an error about permission denied for file 'filename', just execute

> sudo chmod -R 777 'filename'

Then I can open IDE without sudo, and import tensorflow successfully.